# SQL error creating views (with nested tables)

Tags: sql, oracle, view, temporal

I'm having trouble with a very basic example of creating a view.
These are the tables:

```
Create or replace type LEVEL_T as object(
  Duties Varchar2(50),
  Charge Number(10),
  NO Date,
  LIDZ Date
);

Create or replace type LEVELS_T as table of LEVEL_T;

Create table BOTS(
  Bot_ID Number(10) constraint pk_bots primary key,
  Name Varchar2(30),
  Class Varchar2(30),
  Start_date Date,
  Levels LEVELS_T
) nested table Levels store as BOTS_LEVELS_COL;
```

Object:

```
Create or replace type OBJ_DATE as object(
  Name Varchar2(30),
  Class Varchar2(30),
  Duties Varchar2(30),
  Charge Number(10),
  NO Date,
  LIDZ Date,
  MEMBER function WORKS(P_DATE in Date) return number
  );
Create or replace type body OBJ_DATE as
  MEMBER function WORKS(p_date in Date) return number is
  begin
    if ((p_date >= self.NO AND p_date < self.LIDZ) OR
     (self.LIDZ IS NULL AND p_date >= self.NO)) then
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
    end if;
  end WORKS;
end;
```

And now i'm trying to make a view out of all this by:

```
Create or replace view VIEW_WORK of OBJ_DATE with object identifier(Name) as 
  Select A.Name, A.Class, B.Duties, B.Charge, B.NO, B.LIDZ
  From BOTS A, table(A.Levels) B;
```

And keep getting an error starting at line 1: ORA-01730: invalid number of column names specified; 01730. 00000 -  "invalid number of column names specified".
Was playing around with this for a bit and could only manage to get it to work when removing the part around "object identifier", but then calling the function WORKS (a bit ironical) doesn't when attempted to test the view. I'm completely stuck right now, so any tips on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Oracle? That builds OK in 12c (on livesql.oracle.com).

Comment: 10G enterprise on a Win7 VM